# build archive fails but build from react-native run-ios works

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

my react-native project builds and run from npx react-native run-ios and also it runs from xcode. now i am almost done with what i want to do and wanted to publish a version for test flight on app store but i cant archive the product which is how i used to do before. it fails right away with some swift error. in this work i added a dummy swift file and xcode also added bridge file as part of it. here is the error i get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Been there,
make sure all the three pod, project and target have the same IOS Deployment Target.